# CSRF in Rails applications. How to protect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newby in a Rails security and I don't understand one thing. There is CSRF vulnerability, and there is protect_from_forgery method in Rails to generate token and protect my application from bad queries from other sites. It's good, but this sites can parse this token from my site, and use CSRF vulnerability. I don't understand how I can protect my application completely. Thanks in advance.

P.S. Rails 4

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are actually using the CSRF protection provided by default.

> but this sites can parse this token from my site, and use CSRF
>   vulnerability.

**Nope, they can't.** That's precisely how this protection works. **CSRF token is different in each session**, and the attacker attempting to fake a request has no way of knowing which CSRF token is valid for you right now. Or, more precisely, **what token will be valid** at the time you'd be making a desired (by the attacker) request, because that **token is generated randomly** and should therefore be **unpredictable**.

However, this token can be sniffed from a victim's connection as a result of a Man-In-The-Middle (a much more difficult) attack, which can be, in turn, countered by forcing SSL.

Rails Guides have [a section on CSRF countermeasures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures).

Answer (score 0):

On each request `protect_from_forgery` will add

```
<head>
  <!- ... ->
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="xoYoj25LyBvoSlKby4cntwJcVbYhQ38P023yGC6Jecc=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

and to every form

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="xoYoj25LyBvoSlKby4cntwJcVbYhQ38P023yGC6Jecc=" />
```

and also it will add

```
cookies[:_csrf_token] = "xoYoj25LyBvoSlKby4cntwJcVbYhQ38P023yGC6Jecc="
```

Then on each request it will verify that the `cookies[:_csrf_token]` is the same as a query string param (`?authenticity_token=XX`) OR a header (`X-CSRF-Token: XX`), you can see it [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/79d50ce3104d2ff4a3964b12139120b85dce35e7/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L252-L253).

The comparison is done [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/79d50ce3104d2ff4a3964b12139120b85dce35e7/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L307-L315).

To know in depth how this works, read the whole file, all the magic happens there.

Going back to the initial question that a malicious site could parse the token from your page, well, all they will have is a random token that doesn't match the same token in the cookies of the attacked user.